# Can I run a bond cable through a hole in a wall shared by plastic conduit?

Tags: code-compliance

200 amp service upgrade. Can I run a bond cable through a hole in a wall shared by plastic conduit? If not how far away from the conduit do I need to stay?

Comment: By "bond cable", are you talking about some sort of bonding jumper or grounding electrode conductor?

Answer (score 2):

### There's no spacing requirement...

The NEC does not have any specific spacing requirement between conduits carrying power wires and bonding or grounding conductors.  (In fact, it'd be legal to run the water main bond *inside* the same conduit, with it departing the rest of the wires at whatever junction box is at the other end of the conduit run.)

### ...but hole size might be an issue

However, if your conduit runs through studs or plates, not just sheathing, you may run into issues with the maximum permitted hole size in the studs, based on the 40%/60% rules in the IRC.  (That is, you are only allowed to take up 40% of the width of the stud with a hole, with a boost to 60% if you reinforce the hole by sistering the stud or putting a stud shoe around the hole.)

As a result, I'd recommend boring a separate small hole in said stud(s) for this bonding wire, several inches up or down from the hole for the conduit.  This way, one won't damage any stud shoes that may be present at the conduit hole, and won't have to worry about notching or oversizing the existing hole, either.